# MapStruct Java Streams

Tags: java, rest, stream, java-stream, mapstruct

Hello I am quite new to streams etc, just for training purpose I am trying to build simple api with mapstruct. 
My problem is that I dont really know how to return converted Parent value with also converted field in this entity.

Here is my simple ObjecDTO

```
public class RecipeDTO {


    private Integer id;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private String imgUrl;

    private String directions;

    private String prepTime;

    private Integer servings;

    private String category;

    private Set<IngredientDTO> ingredientDTOSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Entity

```
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "recipe_id")
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "recipe_title")
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "recipe_description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "recipe_img_url")
    private String imgUrl;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "recipe_direction")
    private String directions;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "prep_time")
    private String prepTime;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "servings")
    private Integer servings;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Ingredient> ingredients = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Service (only one method)

```
@Override
    public List<RecipeDTO> findAll() {

        log.debug("\n" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " -> findAll() \n");

        return recipeRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(recipe -> RecipeMapper.INSTANCE.recipeToRecipeDTO(recipe))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {IngredientMapper.class})
public interface RecipeMapper {

    RecipeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(RecipeMapper.class);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "ingredients", target = "ingredientDTOSet")
    })
    RecipeDTO recipeToRecipeDTO(Recipe recipe);


}
```

Ho to convert nested beans?
When I am trying to get all Recipes exception is thrown

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.mateuszgeborski.recipeappapi.api.mapper.RecipeMapperImpl.ingredientSetToIngredientDTOSet(RecipeMapperImpl.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mateuszgeborski.recipeappapi.api.mapper.RecipeMapperImpl.recipeToRecipeDTO(RecipeMapperImpl.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.mateuszgeborski.recipeappapi.service.RecipeServiceImpl.lambda$findAll$0(RecipeServiceImpl.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at etc..

It looks like there is are Ingredients, but when I am working with Recipe not DTO everything is fine..

Comment: Its a bit difficult to tell without the generated code. Normally MapStruct includes null checks. So, could it be that the source set includes a null element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing the `componentModel = "spring"` with the `Mappers` factory. When you use the spring component model then the used mappers are autowired within the generated class and the `Mappers` factory only initializes the instance. This means that your recipe mapper is not injected.

In order to solve it you should either use the default componentModel everywhere or use spring and inject your mapper.

P.S. The way you are doing the mapping now is not really performant. You can just add a method for mapping lists to the mapper and invoked that instead of using streams.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the map function of the streams

```
List<Recipe> list = ... //however you get your original list
List<RecipeDTO> dtos = list.stream().map(mapper::convert).collect(Collectors.toList);
```

---

I assume your mapstruct method is called "convert", and the variable of the mapper is called "mapper"

---

The map of the list will call the given method (mapper::convert) for every entry in the stream, and the stream will afterwards contain all the return values of all the calls of this method. so in you case: it will convert every entry of your list, and afterwards the list will contain all converted elements

Afterwards you only need to collect the stream again, so you have a list again

---

after your edit this answer is no longer valid, because you changed the question and used already my answer.

To your  follow-up question:
to convert nested beans in general: as long as the structure of the nested beans are identical, mapstruct will do the work out of the box. If you have differences, you have to annotate them. I can not tell you the differences between your Ingrediant and IngrediantDTO, without seeing this part of your code.

You can try to look in the generated class, and have a look at the line which causes the NullPointerException. So you have a glue what is the difference. And than annotate this to the mapper interface

For nested beans in general:
1) you can add a interface method "ingredientToIngredientDTO" in your mapper. and annotate differences (if needed) right to this method. MapStruct will use it for the recipeToRecipeDTO method!
2) you can annotate nested differences. For example  @Mapping(source = "ingredients.nameA", target = "ingredientDTOSet.nameB")

But you are asking now a totally different question than in the beginning, and to answer it, I would need much more information. So I would prefer to reedit it to the original question. And ask a new one with sufficient information, if my hints was not enough

Comment: Thank you for quick response, Ive updated post with mapper interface also. Could you be so kind and try to help me once agian?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question on java stream. Java stream api is invoking `recipeToRecipeDTO` method, which is failing. Ideally the method `recipeToRecipeDTO` should be able to convert whole Recipe object to RecipeDTO.

To solve the problem, you need to add a method in `RecipeMapper` which converts one `Ingredient` entity object to `IngredientDTO`.